# Why pywinauto fail to get ListView item from a 32-bit app?

Tags: pywinauto

**Environment:**

win7/64-bit

python2.7/32-bit

pywinauto/0.6.3

target_app/32-bit

**Code:**

```
app = Application().connect(path='C:\\new_tdx_zcgl\\TdxW.exe')
while not app.windows_() or not app.TdxW_MainFrame_Class.Exists():
    time.sleep(.5)
_list = app.TdxW_MainFrame_Class.ListView
cols = _list.Columns()
ites = _list.Items()
print "------------------------"
print "|".join([col["text"] for col in cols])
for i in range(_list.ItemCount()):
    print "|".join([ites[i*len(cols)+j].Text()for j in range(len(cols))])
print "------------------------"
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\zd_python\my_pyauto.py", line 28, in     <module>
    print "|".join([ites[i*len(cols)+j].Text()for j in range(len(cols))])
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 194, in text
    return self._readitem()[1]
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site- packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 167, in _readitem
     ', item_index = ' + str(self.item_index) + ', subitem_index = ' +  str(self.subitem_index))
RuntimeError: We should never get to this part of ListView.get_item(),    retval = 0, GetLastError() = 0, item_index = 0, subitem_index = 0
```

**Descriptions:**

When I call `ites[0].Text()`, the error appears also.

And when I change python version to 64-bit, the error still exists.

And I can get the item_count of the ListView, but can not get the text.

What's the problem of my code, and what should I do?

Comment: Hmm... This is very interesting. First such a case during last 5 years. :)
You can try using another backend: `Application(backend="uia")`. It uses MS UI Automation technolgy and should work with list views more reliably (doesn't matter it's 32-bit or 64-bit app / Python). Though need some learning. The [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) is a good starting point for learning differences in these 2 backends.

Comment: I try to use `Application(backend="uia")`, but it perhaps doesn't work. It just can show ListViewHeader but not ListViewItem.

Comment: Is it possible to share some partial version of the app with this list view but some fake text data? Maybe privately by gmail: `"vasily-v-ryabov".replace("-", ".")`. It will help to reproduce and debug the issue on my side.